# Process Doesn't End When Closed

Tags: python, tkinter

I built a web-scraper application with Python. It consists of three main parts:

1. The GUI (built on tkinter)
2. A Client (controls interface between front- and back-end)
3. Back-end code (various threaded processes).

The problem I have is that when the user hits X to exit the program instead of quitting through the interface, it seems like root.destroy() never gets called and the application runs forever, even though the window does disappear. This ends up consuming vast amounts of system resources.

I have tried setting all threads to Daemon without much success. Is there any other reason the program would keep eating up CPU after exit?

Comment: Your program is multi-threaded.  Is it possible that when one thread ends (the gui), the other threads live on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to set ***all*** threads to `daemon`. You want to set the client thread and the back-end thread to daemon. That way, when the GUI thread dies, the threads with `daemon` set to `True` end as well.

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects):

> A thread can be flagged as a “daemon thread”. The significance of this flag is that the entire Python program exits when only daemon threads are left.

Comment: So... the GUI thread should **not** be set to daemon?

What about child threads? The back-end threads spawn many child threads. Can I just set the parent thread to daemon, or should these all be daemon as well?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes, that's what I'm saying. An easy way to do this is to set every thread to a daemon thread except the GUI. This includes all of the child threads spawned by the back-end thread.

Comment: Yeah I just had to hunt them all down. There are quite a few modules in the package, so thankfully I had been using 

    **from threading import Thread**

which was easy enough to replace with:

    **from ..package.sub import DaemonThread as Thread**

making all spawned threads daemonic.